# boost::asio::tcp::socket Close and cancel without handlers being called

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing a server with boost's asio library.  The server handles many concurrent connections using a collection of Connection objects (a wrapper class around boost::asio::tcp::socket).  Within the Connection class, the socket is constantly being read from using socket.async_read_some(...) and whenever the read handler is invoked with new data, socket.async_read_some() is immediately called again for more data to be read.

Now, the server may decide to disconnect a client for some reason, so the natural thing to do is to call connection.close() which in turn calls socket.close(), which will cause all pending async operation to be canceled.  This causes the read handler (bound to a method within class Connection) to be invoked with boost::asio::error::operation_aborted.  And my problem is: I don't want this to happen.

After socket.close(), I'd like to destroy the socket and the connection and then remove its pointer from the server's list of active clients.  However the read handler won't be called until the next iteration of io_service.run(), which means that I cannot immediately destroy the socket or the read handler I had passed to socket.async_read_some() until the handler has been invoked with the error.  So I have to delay the destruction of those objects somehow; that's annoying.

Is there a safe way to either

- Cancel pending async operations *without* any handler to be invoked, so I can safely destroy the socket immediately after socket.close(), or
- to safely know when no more handlers can potentially be called

Or am I approaching this entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an async.operation is complete - either successfuly or with error - its completion handler is invoked. This is important guarantee, and I don't think it's good idea to try and "hack" this behavior.
The problem you encountered in your use-case is usually sovled by using shared_ptr (shared_from_this idiom): bind `shared_ptr<Connection>` to the handlers, don't issue another async_read when you get operation_aborted (or some other error), so that when all the handlers are done the Connection object is destroyed with its socket.

Comment: This sounds very good.  I sure do not use shared_ptr enough and didn't even know about enable_shared_from_this.  I used to do this: "socket.async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(&Connection::done_connect, this, _1))", so now I would just add an additional "shared_from_this()" to the bind call and update the method signature for an additional shared_ptr even though the actual shared_ptr would not even be used in the handler?  I.e. the shared_ptr is just there to guarantee the object still exists.  Sounds right?

Comment: At least I implemented it this way and it works very well now.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @jlh, it's not quite correct to say that the shared_ptr "would not be used in the handler". If you bind a member function to shared_ptr, it's stored within the binder (the functor created with bind() ), and de-referenced on the functor invocation. As a result, the pointee lives as long as the functor lives.

Comment: I think I first didn't implement it the way you had it in mind, because I was binding a shared_ptr to the callback in *addition* to binding 'this'.  (See my first comment)  So the shared_ptr was indeed never used (excepted for the implicit use of keeping the object alive).  I now fixed it, so the call now looks like "socket.async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(&Connection::done_connect, shared_from_this(), _1))".  This is probably what you meant and now it is true that the shared_ptr gets dereferenced for calling the method.  Thanks again!